# Trouble loading files with Emacs

Tags: emacs

this has happened to me twice recently. I always use emacs on my Mac for the longest time for coding. Recently I wrote two fortran files, both of them just around 300 lines. When I try to open them with emacs, it says "Loading fortran...done" in the lower buffer area but nothing appears on the screen and the terminal hangs. The same file works perfectly fine with VI or with any other editor. I use emacs always for all million other fortran files I use, so I doubt it has anything to do with my Emacs settings.

I am using Emacs 22.1.1
Any ideas what might be happening?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try taking all the code from the file and copying it over to another program with a brand new file and saving it with your preferred encoding and line endings, and then trying to open it up again with Emacs?

Comment: Try `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and then open a Fortran file. Do you get an error backtrace?

Comment: Try `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit`, open the file, and then hit `C-g` when it hangs. That should give you a backtrace.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't given much information to go by, but there are a few things you can try to help debug this:

- Open emacs with `emacs -q` to prevent your init.el from loading. This will indicate whether there's something in your configuration that is causing the crash, or whether it's a problem with Emacs 22.
- Type `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and then open a Fortran file. You may be lucky and get an error backtrace that you can inspect.
- Delete byte-compiled elisp files (files with the *.elc* extension). This includes byte-compiled versions of your init.el and 3rd-party elisp <sup>1</sup>.

I'm sure you have your reasons for sticking with Emacs 22, but if you have the option, do try a [more recent version](http://emacsformacosx.com/). You may find you do not experience this problem with Emacs 24.3 .

<sub>1: I have experienced segfaults due to bad byte-compiled elisp files.</sub>

Comment: I opened emacs with "emacs -q" but still got the problem. Those two files hang. And I installed the emacs 24.3 and tried the same and still those files are giving me error. The same files work fine on other machines with emacs. I am not sure what is causing the problem. I couldn't try the "M-x" suggestion you gave me as I don't know how to do "M-x" on Mac. Any more suggestions?

Comment: That'll be option-x (or however you normally invoke commands in Emacs).